# yfiles stop user from being able to resize nodes

Tags: actionscript-3, yfiles

So I have a `GraphEditorInputMode` that I use to set up my `GraphCanvasComponent` input modes. What I am struggling with is stopping the user from being able to resize the individual nodes.

```
    inputMode = graphView.graphInputMode;
    var graphCanvas:GraphCanvasComponent = graphView.graphCanvas;
    inputMode.selectableItems = GraphItemTypes.NODE | GraphItemTypes.EDGE;
    inputMode.marqueeSelectableItems = GraphItemTypes.NODE | GraphItemTypes.EDGE;

    inputMode.nodeCreator = graphView.createNode;

    inputMode.createEdgeInputMode = new CustomCreateEdgeInputMode(graphView.graphDocument.graph);

    inputMode.createEdgeInputMode.connectToCandidatesOnly = true;
    inputMode.createEdgeInputMode.showPortCandidates = true;
    inputMode.createEdgeInputMode.selfloopCreationAllowed = false;
    inputMode.nodeCreationAllowed = false;
    inputMode.moveLabelModeEnabled = false;
    inputMode.labelEditingAllowed = true;
    inputMode.textEditorModeEnabled = true;
    inputMode.createEdgeModeEnabled = true;

    graphCanvas.inputModes.addItem(inputMode);
```

The closest thing I can find is the java docs (I am writing in AS3, very poor documentation) [HotSpotMode](http://docs.yworks.com/yfiles/doc/api/y/view/HotSpotMode.html), but can not figure out how to implement my own HotSpotMode input handling.

Answer (score 1):

Did you take a look at the examples that come with the package? They contain an example specifically for this use-case: You need to adjust the IReshapeHandleProvider interface accordingly. The "very poor documentation" is [here](http://docs.yworks.com/yfilesflex/doc/api/client/index.html) and [here](http://docs.yworks.com/yfilesflex/doc/dguide/index.html).